# How to make a negative fact in PROLOG

Tags: prolog

If I have a fact "Anna is a person" in PROLOG I write for example:

```
person(anna).
```

But what do I write if I have a fact "table is not a Person". I tried

```
not(person(table)).
```

But this doesn't work. How do I write negative facts?

Comment: Typically you don't have to assert the negative as a fact. The absence of the positive fact or a proving rule results in failure in prolog. So if you only assert that `person(anna)`, then `person(anna).` will be true (succeed), but `person(table).` will be false (fail, or is not provable) as expected. Also, the query, `person(X).` will only yield `X = anna` as expected.

Comment: Thanks @lurker So much logic that the obvious thinks won't be seen -.-*

Comment: I posted a slightly more elaborate answer, building upon what I said in the comment. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Prolog, typically you don't have to assert the negative as a fact. The absence of the positive fact or a proving rule results in failure (or more accurately, "lack of provability").

So if you only assert that `person(anna)`, then the query `person(anna).` will be true (succeed, or be provable), but `person(table).` will be false (fail, or is not provable) as expected. Also, the query, `person(X).` will only yield `X = anna` as expected.

By default, if you query `person(X)` and there are no persons defined, Prolog will give an error indicating that `person` is an unknown predicate. If you would rather that Prolog simply fails in that case, there's an option you can set (I know in SWI Prolog in particular, but I don't recall what the option is), or you can declare `person/1` to be a *dynamic predicate* if you plan to assert `person` facts into your database dynamically as the program executes.

As part of a predicate definition, you might want to indicate that a warm-blooded animal is a mammal but is not a person. In that case, you might have:

```
warm_blooded_animal(X) :-
    mammal(X),
    \+ person(X).
```

This is a little contrived just as an example. In this case, you'd more likely define `mammal` in terms of the characteristic of being warm-blooded, etc, rather than the other way around. But you get the idea... Note that the operator `not/1` is deprecated in favor of the ISO standard `\+/1`.

Answer (score 3):

Actually you could use a rule like `person(table):-false.`